# Printing a bill using HTML CSS - Printing A4

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print a bill which is generated as an HTML page. I am using @media print, and have tried giving page size. However, the length of the bill is always coming as long as an A4 page. I tried checking if there are any printer settings that says A4 and have not found anything of that sort. I have also given page break at the end of the div which is my bill

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem after several hours of breaking my head. I am leaving this for someone else who might face a similar issue.

When printing through Chrome, there is a setting called "Headers and Footers" - It basically prints the url of the page at the top and bottom. However, if you uncheck this option, it will print it properly